# Cannot resolve symbol error in intellij with Scala with Odersky's programming in scala book

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm following Martin odersky's Programming in Scala book (second edition, page 101) to learn scala. I received the resolve symbol error in intellij when following his code.
The code is:

```
class Rational (n: Int, d: Int)
{
  require( d != 0)
  val numer: Int = n
  val denom: Int  =d
  override def toString = numer + "/" + denom

  def add(that: Rational): Rational =
  new Rational (
    numer * that.denom + that.numer * denom, denom * that.denom
  )
}

val onehalf= new Rational(1,2)
```

The error received says cannot resolve symbols that.denom or that.numer. However, the code does run and compile when called to produd=ce 1/2. Can someone explain why this error occurs?

edit: I want to add im using the scala worksheet part of intellij idea

Comment: Have you tried restarting intellij idea?

Comment: Also try: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/cleaning-system-cache.html

Comment: @Archeg after trying those steps, the code still compiles but the error persits

Comment: this code works at my side, so it's nothing wrong about it. It should be IDE which behaves wrong. I've seen the same problem with PyCharm which is based on IntelliJ Idea, and I actually had to reinstall it for the problem to be gone. You can try that, or just ignore the issue if it appears only in a single place

Comment: @Archeg after having tried everything, the erorr still persists :/

Comment: Sorry, I do not have any more ideas. You should probably contact Jetbrains directly, or wait until somebody else answer something

Comment: also, do you use SBT? If yes, you might try switching to IDEA. And you could try to default your settings in intellij, there are lots of stuff there you can mess with. But these are just guesses, so it could be better to contact somebody on Jetbrains forum

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the project & 'Synchronize project' did it for me